# Char 23: warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use an explicit string comparison function instead) [-Wstring-compare]

Tags: c++

When I trying to run this code in leetcode, it showing following error.

I have tried running removing the " " with ' ' its still not working

```
string reverseWords(string s) {
        s.insert(0," ");
        string st="";
        string ans="";
        for(int i= s.size();i>=0;i--)
        {
            while(s[i]!=" ")
            {
                st+=s[i];
            }
            reverse(st.begin(),st.end());
            ans.push_back(st);
            st="";
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: Recall how to code chars and string literals.

Comment: Replace `while(s[i]!=" ")` with `while(s[i]!=' ')`. Understand the difference between a string and a char. A string is a sequence of characters. `s` is a string, so `s[i]` is a char. So when you do a comparison you need another char, so `' '` not `" "`.

Comment: With that change your code will compile but it will not work. Think about this loop `while(s[i]!=' ')  { st+=s[i]; }` When do you think that loop will stop? Where does `i` change in that loop?

Comment: That does not seem to be the only error. Think about the initial value of `i`, here `i = s.size();` Almost the next thing you do with `i` is `s[i]`. How do you think that will work when `i` equals the size of the string?

Comment: @john actually, since C++11 it will work just fine, it will return a reference to the terminating `'\0'` char of the string. That is well-defined behavior. Now, that may not be what the code should be processing, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::string::operator[]` returns a single `char` in the `std::string` object. You are comparing that single `char` to a string literal (aka a `const char[]` array), which is not a valid operation. You need to compare a `char` to another `char` instead.

Change this:

`while(s[i]!=" ")`

To this

`while(s[i]!=' ')`

Also, you are trying to `push_back()` a `std::string` into another `std::string`, but `std::string::push_back()` does not take a `std::string`, it takes a `char` instead.

Change this:

`ans.push_back(st);`

To this:

`ans += st;`

Also, your `while` loop will run endlessly once `s[i]` reaches a non-space character in the `string`, because the condition you are testing will never evaluate as false, as you are comparing the same char over and over without changing `s` or `i`. You need to decrement `i` until a space character or the front of the string is reached.

Answer (score 2):

The warning message you're seeing is related to the line `while(s[i]!=" ")`.

In C++, the `!=` operator is used for comparing two values for inequality. However, in this case, you're comparing a character `s[i]` with a string literal `" "`, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

To fix this warning, you should use single quotes to create a character literal instead of a string literal. So, you should change the line `while(s[i]!=" ")` to `while(s[i]!=' ')`.

Here's the corrected code:

```cpp
string reverseWords(string s) {
    s.insert(0," ");
    string st="";
    string ans="";
    for(int i= s.size();i>=0;i--)
    {
        while(s[i]!=' ')
        {
            st+=s[i];
        }
        reverse(st.begin(),st.end());
        ans.push_back(st);
        st="";
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Note that this code still has other issues that need to be fixed before it will work as intended.

Here's my possible corrections for the code:

```cpp
string reverseWords(string s) {
    s.insert(0, " ");
    string st = "";
    string ans = "";
    for (int i = s.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (i >= 0 && s[i] != ' ') {
            st += s[i];
            i--;
        }
        reverse(st.begin(), st.end());
        ans += st;
        st = "";
    }
    return ans;
}
```

1. The loop condition should start from `s.size() - 1` instead of `s.size()`, since C++ arrays are zero-indexed and the loop needs to iterate over all characters in the string.
2. The loop should iterate until the beginning of the string, which has index 0. So the loop condition should be `i >= 0`.
3. The `push_back` method of the `ans` string should be called with a single character, not a string. So the line `ans.push_back(st);` should be changed to `ans += st;`.

**An edit**
Pointed by @Remy Lebeau to change `ans += st[0]` to `ans += st`. I appreciate for pointing out my mistake Sir.

Comment: Why go to the trouble of extracting a whole word and reversing it, just to return only the 1st character of it? `ans += st[0];` should propably be `ans += st;` instead.